# Extracting strings from a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, string, pandas, dataframe

I'm here again hoping to find a solution to my coding nightmare. I have a dictionary `term_dict` with list of terms as keys and term category as values. And a dataframe `data` with ID and Notes columns. The task is to find matching terms in the `data.Notes` using the `term_dict` for every `data.ID` record.

```
  term_dict{                   
  Ibuprofen 800mg     :     Drug
  Hip Replacement Surgery : Treatment
  Tylenol   AM          :   Drug
  Mild Dislocation      :   Treatment
  Advil                  :  Drug
  Fractured Tibia       :   Treatment
  Quinone               :   Drug
  Fever                 :   Treatment
  Penicillin 250mg      :   Drug
  Histerectomy          :   Treatment
  Surgical removal of bunion :  Treatment
  Therapy               :   Treatment
  Bunion                :   Treatment
  Hospita X             :   Location
  mg                    :   Dosage
  stop                  :   Exclusion
}

data:
ID      Notes                        
604     Take 2 tablets of advil & 3 caps of pen   
        250mg twice daily                          
602     Stop pen but cont. with advil
        as needed for the fracture
210     2 tabs of Tyl 3x daily for 5 days         
607     nan
700     surgery scheduled for 01/01/2017
515     nan                                       
019     Call my office if bunion pain persist     
        after 3 days
604     f/up appt. @Hospital X
```

So far, this is my code:

```
lists = []
for s in data['Notes']:
    cleanNotes = " " + " ".join(re.split(r'[^a-z 0-9]|[w/]',s.lower())) + " "
    for k, v in term_dict.items():
        k = " %s "%k
        if k in cleanNotes and v != exclusion:
            if k in cleanNotes and v == 'drug':
                lists.append(k)
                data['Drug'] = ':'.join(str(lists))
            elif k in cleanNotes and v == 'location':
                lists.append(k)
                data['Location'] = ' '.join(str(lists))
            elif k in cleanNotes and v == 'treatment':
                lists.append(k)
                data['Treatment'] = ':'.join(str(lists))
            elif k in cleanNotes and v == 'dosage':
                lists.append(k)
                data['Dosage'] = ':'.join(str(lists))
        else:
            for s in data.Notes:
            matches = list(datefinder.find_dates(s.lower()))
            data['Date'] = ', '.join([str(dates) for dates in matches])
```

....and my output is not what's expected because the code just populates the new columns of the dataframe with matches from he last record of the dataframe:

```
data:
ID      Notes                                       Drug                Dosage      Location        Treatment   Date                
604     Take 2 tablets of advil & 3 caps of pen     advil                           Hospital X
        250mg twice daily                          
602     Stop pen but cont. with advil               advil                           Hospital X  
        as needed for the fracture
210     2 tabs of Tyl 3x daily for 5 days           advil    
607     nan                                         advil
700     surgery scheduled for 01/01/2017            advil                                               
515     nan                                         advil
019     Call my office if bunion pain persist       advil                                               
        after 3 days
604     f/up appt. @Hospital X. cont w/advil        advil                           Hospital X
```

***But expected Output:

```
data:
ID      Notes                                       Drug                Dosage      Location        Treatment   Date                
604     Take 2 tablets of advil & 3 caps of pen     advil:penicilin     0:250mg
        250mg twice daily                          
602     Stop pen but cont. with advil               advil                                           fracture
        as needed for the fracture
210     2 tabs of Tyl 3x daily for 5 days           Tylenol
607     nan
700     surgery scheduled for 01/01/2017                                                            surgery     01/01/2017
515     nan                                       
019     Call my office if bunion pain persist                                                       bunion
        after 3 days
604     f/up appt. @Hospital X. cont w/advil        advil                           Hospital X
```

I'd be more than grateful if I can get this duplication fixed. Thanks!

Comment: What is `words`? Why do you use it?

Comment: @COLDSPEED - that's the clean version of every note in the Notes column. Clean - meaning free from any/all special characters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The essence of your error is this. You assign *every element* of that column to the same value:

```
In [114]: import pandas as pd

In [115]: df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(50, 4), columns=list('ABCD'))

In [116]: df.head()
Out[116]: 
          A         B         C         D
0 -0.896291 -0.277551  0.926559  0.522212
1 -0.265559 -1.300435 -0.079514 -1.083569
2 -0.534509  0.298264 -1.361829  0.750666
3  0.318937 -0.407164  0.080020  0.499435
4 -0.161574 -1.012471  0.631092  1.368540

In [117]: df['NewCol'] = 'something here'

In [119]: df.head()
Out[119]: 
          A         B         C         D          NewCol
0 -0.896291 -0.277551  0.926559  0.522212  something here
1 -0.265559 -1.300435 -0.079514 -1.083569  something here
2 -0.534509  0.298264 -1.361829  0.750666  something here
3  0.318937 -0.407164  0.080020  0.499435  something here
4 -0.161574 -1.012471  0.631092  1.368540  something here
```

To fix this, what you can do is create empty columns up front, like this:

```
In [120]: df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(50, 1), columns=['Notes'])

In [121]: df['Drug'] = ""
     ...: df['Location'] = ""
     ...: df['Treatment'] = ""
     ...: df['Dosage'] = ""
     ...: 

In [122]: df.head()
Out[122]: 
      Notes Drug Location Treatment Dosage
0  0.325993                               
1 -0.561066                               
2  0.555040                               
3  0.001332                               
4  0.400009
```

When looping over notes, use an enumerated loop:

```
for i, s in enumerate(data['Notes']):
```

Then, when the need arises, just set that cell appropriately:

```
df.set_value(i, 'Drug', 'advil')
```

Comment: @COLDSPEED I tried your sample solution and I got this error `ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis`

Comment: @CodeLearner Hmm, it seems your data frame has duplicate indices, for whatever reason, preventing you from inserting those values in there (not a byproduct of my code unless it has to do with our pandas versions being different). You can add this line before the loop: `data = data.reset_index(drop=True)` I think it should work.

Comment: @COLDSPEED Yup that solved the `ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis` problem. However, `matches` list only picks the first matched item, (i.e `advil` instead of `advil:penicilin`. since each note often has multiple matches, how can this be fixed?

Comment: @CodeLearner Well, your notes has "pen 250mg" but your dict has no such key (only Penicillin 250mg). Is that normal? That may be the problem.

Comment: @COLDSPEED my real dataset does. what I have up here is synthetic data